# Incorrect syntax near the word 'END' in SQL

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I'm making a stored procedure in SQL but I get the error Incorrect syntax near the word 'END' at line 1 position 1 but the line 1 in my code is:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[upd_facility_new] @Tcifno int
```

Comment: Show the line with `END`, better, show the complete SP.

Comment: And the line before it

Comment: Probably because a Sproc needs to be in its own batch and requires a body.

Comment: "Create procedure" syntax should be find any error that to display line no 1 error

Comment: Show the **complete** SQL you are running.

Comment: Show me complete procedure, how can we get where did you mistake without it. Your question deserve downvote. But i am not giving because you are new on this website (according to your points).

Answer (score 1):

**Try this format:**

```
USE [dbName]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_name]    Script Date: 08/14/2015 10:34:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_name]


AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM TableName


END
```

Comment: using SP in the start of a  procedure name is bad practice. SP is used for sqlservers internal procedures and you risk name conflicts. I would assume the stored procedure already contains an END since it compiled. There is an error elsewhere which could pretty much be anything, so I would not consider this helpful

Comment: Thanks @Evgeny. Sproc compiled when I included BEGIN after the AS. Sorry folks, newbie here.

Comment: @AbbyGragasin if this helped please Up the post and mark as answered.